# Enabling NSButton with bindings, based on NSTableView selection

Tags: cocoa, button, binding, nstableview

I have a NSWindow containing an NSButton and an NSTableView.

I'd like the button to be enabled if and only if the table contains at least one item, and exactly one item is selected. (The table does not allow multiple selection.)

What can I bind the button's enabled binding to to make this happen?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the typical way a Remove/Delete button is enabled. Is binding to the controller's -canRemove property enough?

Comment: Have you considered switching to an array controller? It makes such things super-easy.

Answer (score 15):

This is an old thread, but here are my 2 cents:
Use and array controller and bind the button's enabled state to

Controller Key: selectedObjects
Model Key Path: @count

Works fine.

Comment: Of all the information here, this is the only technique that works for me.

Comment: Thank you.. I was just about to write some code to create a new boolean property instead :)

Comment: Don't forget to bind the Table View's selection to the array controller, not just it's content.

Answer (score 2):

Try binding to the array controller's `selectedObjects`, model key path `count`, with no value transformer.

Note that this would be unsafe if you allowed multiple selection: For one thing, the `count` could easily be neither `YES` nor `NO`; for another, if the user selected a multiple of 256 items, the lowest byte of the count would be 0, so the `BOOL` value would be `NO` even though there is a selection.

Comment: I don't have an ArrayController anywhere. The table view uses a delegate and a data source.

Comment: Then using Bindings is a bit pointless for this case, isn't it? Create an outlet for the button and set its enabled state directly when the selection changes (via delegate message).

Comment: Or create a property `buttonEnabled` in the model and bind to that. If you really want to bind to the `NSTableView` you could bind in the `-awakeFromNib` method the `enabled` property to the table view's `selectedRowIndexes.count` property.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and I got it to work after some efforts.

My button should be disabled if nothing is selected in the "Master Table":

Problems I ran into:

- Use the actual button and not the enclosed Button cell
- Specify `NO = disabled` for Multiple values, No selection etc.
- Bind the `Enabled` property to the Master Table's selection and use a property (`code` in my case), which is present.
- Use the transformer `NSIsNotNil` to enable the button if something is selected in the master table.

[image]